# Excluding health and actuator url in opentelemetry java agent

Tags: java, open-telemetry, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I am using opentelemetry-javaagent.jar. Health check and actuator url are also coming in jaeger. Can I exclude those url patterns somehow in java command itself like -Dotel.exclude.url?

Comment: They don't have this implemented yet. For now, the best alternative is this thread, requiring this implementation. The suggestion is using extension to ignore endpoints.

[https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/1060](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/1060)

Comment: @wallacesilva09 - Thanks for reply. I have already tried extension and it was working. But for that I need to add create extra jar and add it in args. So that I want to avoid.